# Is there a way to disable Pyrogram logging?

Tags: python, logging, pyrogram

I'm using this library only for couple methods, and it's kinda annoying that it's printing a lot of logs beside my own initialization logs.

Tried to get same logger as library gets, `"pyrogram.client"`, and change it's level - nothing changed.
Also `logger.propagate = false` doesn't help.

My friend got no logs from pyrogram by default, though our logger and pyrogram configs are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
```

You can also set the level to `INFO`, but that's up to you.
Here are all the default levels: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels

Comment: Thanks. Changed basicConfig to warning and my own logger to info - now it's works.

Answer (score 0):

A way to go, if you do not want to suppress other loggers:

```
import logging
for name, logger in logging.root.manager.loggerDict.items():
    if name.startswith('pyrogram'):
        logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Optionally, if that's not enough, replace `WARNING` with `ERROR` or `CRITICAL`.